# Await functions but do them synchrony, then call the last function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vue-component, es6-promise

So I am working with Vue, Node and typescript.
I am fetching data that all my other functions are needing, so `getDataForFunction123()` needs an await and its fine.

Then I have 3 functions that is fetching different stuff, not depending on each other. But all answers is used by the last function `updateAfterFunction123IsDone()`. But when I have it like now, we need to wait synchrony for function 1, 2 and 3. It takes a lot of time.
I want to make function 1, 2 and 3 to just do there stuff at the same time but also want to know when all 3 is done and then call `updateAfterFunction123IsDone()`.

Here is the code:

```
async initData () {
  await this.getDataForFunction123();

  await this.function1();
  await this.function2();
  await this.function3();

  this.updateAfterFunction123IsDone();
}
```

I don't think that an `Promise.all()` will solve this issue? Because it is also doing the function in a order and not in the same time? Right? That will not save me time, but save me some error handling?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a Promise is. `Promise.all` doesn't do anything special, it's just a utility method. If you create three promises without `await`ing them, all three will begin to execute immediately in "parallel" (as parallel as you can get in JavaScript, at least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Promise.all` fires once all of its promises are resolved.  So run all of your functions `function1`, `function2`, `function3` immediately, without `await`, and then proceed once their promises are resolved:

```
async initData () {
  await this.getDataForFunction123();

  const p1 = this.function1();
  const p2 = this.function2();
  const p3 = this.function3();

  await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);
  this.updateAfterFunction123IsDone();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I need to read in to Promise.all a bit more I see. Thanks!